# ASP.NET Charting Control only working on some servers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, charts, httphandler

Yesterday we pushed out some changes including the addition of ASP.NET MVC 3 (routing, configuration, etc.) and our ASP.NET charting controls stopped working.  In our development environment the ASP.NET chart control works as expected.  However in our test and production env. we are getting errors from the DefaultControllerFactory as no path can be found for the axd url - "Pages/Secured/ChartImg.axd"

We've tried comparing any differences with the IIS configuration and web.config and made sure the system.webserver node has the correct handler as so...

```
<add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

This has not helped and we are not sure what else could be wrong.  It appears to be the chart handler is not setup correctly, but we have no way of knowing why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Mime type not set in IIS?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098548/axd-files-generate-a-404-error

Comment: It most likely some sort of permission on your IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out we had a compiler directive on the user control that switched the ImageStorageMode property of the charting control based on debug/release builds.  This explained why it was only working on our dev environments that got a debug build and not the other environments.  After discovering that we used the fix from this question [ASP.NET Charting Control no longer working with .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631526/asp-net-charting-control-no-longer-working-with-net-4), which fixed the routing issue we had for the handler when the ImageStorageMode was set to UseHttpHandler.